# Kotlin combine two flows depending from each other

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a data class, `MyThing1`, which has an ID in it. data class MyThing1(val id: String)
I have another data class which we don’t care about its content, but let’s call it `MyThing2`
I have a function that returns a list of `MyThing1`

```
fun myEmitter1(): Flow<List<MyThing1>>
```

I have another Flow that takes in input an ID and returns a flow of objects, so

```
fun myEmitter2(id: String): Flow<MyThing2>
```

For each `MyThing1` received from the flow, I want to combine it with the latest `MyThing2` that gets emitted by `myEmitter2` and return a `Flow<List<CombinedThing>>` given the `CombinedThing` is

```
data class CombinedThing(val myThing1: MyThing1, val myThing2: MyThing2) .
```

and where every times myThing1 changes, it observes `myEmitter2(id)` and every time `myThing2` emits, it emits a `CombinedThing`.

In a diagram, I'd like something like this:

```
[mt11,mt12]--------------------------------------------------------------------------
observe for id 1 ----mt211-----------------------------------------------------------
--[observe for id 2]------------------------mt212-------------------------------------

---------------------[CT(mt11,mt211(1))]----[CT(mt11,mt211(1)),CT(mt2,mt212)]---------
```

Comment: I don't know Kotlin Flow, but after quick search it looks like Rx, so a Zip method could apply: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/zip.html

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for something that takes as an input a `Flow<List<MyThing1>>` and returns a `Flow<Flow<List<CombinedThing>>>`, so it's a Flow of Flow of Lists? Or Do you want to return a `Flow<List<Flow<CombinedThing>>>`? Or you want to flatten it to only a `Flow<List<CombinedThing>>`?

Answer (score 6):

So the inputs to `myEmitter2` should be the IDs of the values from `myEmitter1`?

We could implement this with the `flatMapLatest` and `combine` operators:

```kotlin
myEmitter1().flatMapLatest { myThing1s: List<MyThing1> ->
    val myThing2s: List<Flow<Pair<MyThing1 to MyThing2>> = myThing1s.map { t1 ->
        myEmitter2(t1.id).map { t2 -> t1 to t2 }
    }
    combine(myThing2s) { combined: Array<Pair<MyThing1, MyThing2>> ->
        combined.map { (t1, t2) -> CombinedThing(t1, t2) }
    }
}
```

From [the docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html), `flatMapLatest` creates "a flow that switches to a new flow produced by transform function every time the original flow emits a value". That fits your requirement that "every time `myThing1` changes, it observes `myEmitter2(id)`".

Inside `flatMapLatest`'s transform function, we see each list emitted by `myEmitter1`. We use `map` to turn the `List<MyThing1>` into a list of flows. Each flow will take the values from `myEmitter2` and use `map` (again) to pair them up with the original `myThing1` value. This gives us a `List<Flow<Pair<MyThing1 to MyThing2>>`.

Finally, we use `combine` to turn the list of flows into a `Flow<List<CombinedThing>>`. The `combine` operator takes a list of flows and emits values that are computed by combining the most recently emitted values from each flow. We get an array (I've called it `combined`) containing the most recent value from each of our flows. Using `map`, we can turn that array into a `List` and turn our pair into a `CombinedThing` object.

Comment: This works, but say `myEmitter2` is doing something heavy. Each time `myEmitter1` has new values. All `myEmitter2` flows will be stopped, and created again. Which is quite inefficient. Is there a way to cache `myEmitter2` flow if already seen?